W3 Total Cache and Azure CDN setup
Setup:

W3 Total Cache WordPress plugin installed
Azure CDN activated via W3 Total Cache
All media and theme files synced with CDN
After CDN activation all works fine for ~30min
After ~30 min I got an mixed content error for all my website fonts and website looks broken
After clearing the cache from the server (not from the W3 Total Cache) it works fine again.

What it can be? How to fix this weird issue?
Why the CDN redirects to the http connection suddenly?
Thanks
